# Could we allow linking to subsections of the site FAQ's editable part?

Tags: bug, moderator-tools, site-faq

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Custom sections in FAQ don't work right](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/104861/custom-sections-in-faq-dont-work-right)

Only the first part of [each site's FAQ](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/faq) (the part between »What kind of questions can I ask here?« and »What kind of questions should I not ask here?«) is editable by the site's moderators.

It is possible to add more sections in this part, using the `##` markup, like this:

```
## Do we accept basic level/homework questions?
```

These titles then also show up in the table of contents at the side, but the links don't work - they always only link to the first section, not to the actual section in question. This also disallows linking these sections from outside, like it is possible with the other sections.

Could this be fixed, please?

Comment: Related - http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/73381/moderators-cant-edit-the-what-kind-of-questions-should-i-not-ask-here-sectio, but **NOT** a duplicate

Comment: +1 totally agreed. It'd be much simpler to browse the FAQ and would help us mods to link the specific section when commenting questions.